# Need Help With PHP Function, It doesn't work when i pass value by variable

Tags: php, function, variables

Here's a php function and it works perfectly.

```
$values = array(

        'php' => 'php hypertext processor',

        'other' => array(
            'html' => 'hyper text markup language',
            'css' => 'cascading style sheet',
            'asp' => 'active server pages',
        )

);


function show($id='php', $id2='') {

    global $values;

    if(!empty($id2)) {
        $title = $values[$id][$id2];
    }
    else {
         $title = $values[$id]; 
    }

    echo $title;

}
```

When i execute this `<?php show(other,asp); ?>` it displays active server pages and it works, but when i do it this way it shows an error

```
<?php

$lang = 'other,asp'

show ($lang);

?>
```

It doesn't work., Please help me out here

P.S : It works if i pass variable with single value (no commas)

Comment: Thanks everybody for your answers. Each method you guys provided worked well, I dont know whose answer to mark as correct as all answers are correct, Please help me, Whose answer shall i mark as correct – Roccos 0 secs ago edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you'd like to pass it in the way you have it, 
maybe try using explode:

```
function show($id='php') {

     global $values;
     $ids = explode(',',$id);

     if(!empty($ids[1])) {
         $title = $values[$ids[0]][$ids[1]];
     }
     else {
          $title = $values[$ids[0]]; 
     }

     echo $title;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't pass two variables in one string. Your string `$lang` needs to be split up into two vairables:

```
$lang1 = 'other';
$lang2 = 'asp';

show($lang1, $lang2);
```

Answer (score 2):

> P.S : It works if i pass variable with single value (no commas)

You are assigning `$lang` to the value 'other,asp', and then passing that sole `$lang` variable to the `show` function.  There is no key named "other,asp" in your `$values` array.

Having a comma in the string doesn't mean you're splitting the parameters, it means you're passing a single string value.  You *have* to "pass a variable with a single value", or do it like this for multiple parameter values:

```
$lang = "other";
$sub_lang = "asp";
show ($lang, $sub_lang);
```

Answer (score 2):

It fails because the key `"other,asp"` doesn't exist in `$values`.

In other words, it is trying to evaluate the following:

```
$title = $values['other,asp'];
```

PS, it's always useful to provide an actual error rather than saying "it doesn't work".

Answer (score 2):

This is because $lang will get interpreted as a single argument, so $id2 will be 'other,asp'. You need to pass them into the function separately:

```
$id1 = 'other';
$id2 = 'asp';

show($id1,$id2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning one string instead of the two required... how about rewriting your function to handle them instead?